# Is there a way to backup and restore ACL file and folder permissions on linux the way that there is using icacls in Windows?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, backup, acl

In Windows you can do [this](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/terri/viewing-saving-and-restoring-ntfs-permissions/) (backup and restore ACL permissions) can you do this in Linux?

And to clarify, I mean ACLs in Linux, I do not mean the default permissions modified with `chmod` / `chown`.

Comment: I'm not aware of a tool for backing up just the POSIX ACL's of a directory tree. It'd be useful to have but I don't think it exists. `rsync` and `tar` both support POSIX ACL's but each would require the files themselves be replaced (and in the case of rsync would require a concurrent tree).

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question.  My other question was about the default file system permissions, not the ACLs.